# NumberFormatException on Solr update

Tags: java, solr

When updating the float field **price** on my Solr index I'm getting a NumberFormatException. The **price** definition in schema.xml:

> field name="price" type="tfloat" indexed="true" stored="true"
>   required="false" multiValued="false"

This is how I set the update:

```
Float newVal = 69.9f;
Map<String, Float> partialUpdatePrice = new HashMap<String, Float>();
partialUpdatePrice.put("set", newVal);
doc.addField("price", partialUpdatePrice);
```

When sending the doc to Solr I get this exception in the Solr log:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{set=69.9}"

Thanks

Comment: `{set=69.9}` is not a Number. It's a string.

Comment: Right, but according to this doc: http://heliosearch.org/solr/atomic-updates/ partial updates should be done this way. And if you check newVal you will see that it is a float.

Comment: I noticed that your `doc.addField("price, partialUpdatePrice);` is missing a `"`; Is this your current code?

Comment: No, I simplyfied the code for better understanding and made a mistake, sorry. Corrected now...